# Do I need to standardized age and the outcomes if I want to do a multivariable regression

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, standardization

I want to conduct a multivariate regression.
I decided to standardize other variables such as exposure score.
Do I need to standardize age? It sounds weird if I say increasing 1 SD age is associated with increasing 0.36 SD of the outcomes. So do I need to standardize age?

For gender, maybe there is no need to standardize it?
For outcomes, do I need to standardize the dependent variable? I saw in the previous literature, they could choose to standardize dependent variable or not to. The choice is flexible. I want to confirm whether it is true.

Thanks a lot for your kind help!

Comment: You have missed a huge amount of information on this site about your problem.  First, note that _multivariate_ only applies if you have > 1 dependent variable.  You probably mean multivariable analysis (hence my correction to your tags).  Standardization assumes symmetric covariate distributions and adds nothing but confusion to multivariable models unless you are doing penalization (shrinkage).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help. My aim is to easily interpret the results if I standardize the independent variables. I have tried if I standardized age, the parameters of other independent variables will not change. So I understand you say "it adds nothing".

Comment: Standardization makes the interpretation more, not less difficult, because standard deviations measure how much subjects disagree with one another, not a direct subject-specific effect.  As covered in chapter 5 of [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rms) interpret the model by (1) graphing the whole age effect (usually nonlinear) and (2) getting predicted values at 2 specific ages such as the outer quartiles, and taking the difference in predicted values.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.

Comment: On this site thanks is expressed by upvoting.

Comment: Thanks, because you just add comments rather than answer question, there is no button to upvoting the comments. I am sorry for that.

Comment: To the left of the comment there is an up arrrow.